# How a framework development works without a debugger?

Tags: php, python, debugging

I am quite new with development. In some programming language such as python and PHP there is not a good debugger. How is the development going on without a debugger? just put the logs in the source code? Especially for the framework developers, how do they test their codes?

Thank you very much.

-Stefan-

Answer (score 2):

Your answer concerning the debugging in Python is truly nonsense. Python has a reasonable "pdb" debugger which is useful since years. Apart from that you can have a powerful IDE as WingIDE giving you all debugging and inspection power you need. Making such wild claims about Python is not appropriate. That's why this question deserves a clear downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have looked around before coming to your conclusion. I've worked with two excellent debuggers for PHP. Xdebug and ZendDebug. If you have an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans (both free), it's super easy to debug your app. Just click on the debug menu button :)

Xdebug : http://www.xdebug.org/

Zend Debug : http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt

Eclipse PDT : http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Netbeans : http://netbeans.org/

Answer (score 0):

Python has a debugger: pdb. If you use Werkzeug, then you can also access each frame of a stack trace and debug there on an error

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python developer, but in case of PHP,we do have a debugger. Setting it up and getting to work with it might not be as easy as C# (with VS) or other programming languages. PHP itself is developing and becoming better.

Putting logs is very important and good way to debug. You could also have some print statements, for debugging. Apart from that, you can make use of PHPeclipse IDE and use the debugger. This will help you create breakpoints etc..

You could also setup error reporting in PHP.

Refer to this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/) for setting up you development environment.

Answer (score 0):

python -m pdb foo.py
And even without using that, usually you get detailed tracebacks when an error happens so many people don't know about pdb because they can just read the error message containing everything they ever wanted to know. It's not like C where it just goes boom and says "Segmentation fault" and leaves you with nothing to work on.